# Splitting a huge list into smaller lists and append items to those sublists

Tags: python, list, append, sublist

I have a huge list that was imported from a csv file. This list has over 40,000 string elements. I want to divide each element into an independent list.

This an extract from my list:

```
['090-102  XX.Abcdefg;Female;95 y mÃ¡s aÃ±os;1985;24\n',
 '090-102  XX.Abcdefg;Female;95 y mÃ¡s aÃ±os;1984;52\n', 
 '090-102  XX.Abcdefg;Female;95 y mÃ¡s aÃ±os;1983;60\n', 
 '090-102  XX.Abcdefg;Female;95 y mÃ¡s aÃ±os;1982;61\n', 
 '090-102  XX.Abcdefg;Female;95 y mÃ¡s aÃ±os;1981;63\n', 
 '090-102  XX.Abcdefg;Female;95 y mÃ¡s aÃ±os;1980;48\n']
```

I want each item in the list to be separated into a new list like this:

```
[['090-102  XX.Abcdefg,Female,95 y mÃ¡s aÃ±os,1985,24\n']
 ['090-102  XX.Abcdefg,Female,95 y mÃ¡s aÃ±os,1984,52\n'] 
 ['090-102  XX.Abcdefg,Female,95 y mÃ¡s aÃ±os,1983,60\n'] 
 ['090-102  XX.Abcdefg,Female,95 y mÃ¡s aÃ±os,1982,61\n'] 
 ['090-102  XX.Abcdefg,Female,95 y mÃ¡s aÃ±os,1981,63\n'] 
 ['090-102  XX.Abcdefg,Female,95 y mÃ¡s aÃ±os,1980,48\n']]
```

And I also have to insert new elements (elements from two other lists) into the new separated sublists:

```
other_list = ['XX','XX','XX','XX','XX','XX']
other_list2 = [20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20]
```

So my final output looks like this:

```
[['090-102  XX', 'XX', 20, 'Abcdefg,Female,95 y mÃ¡s aÃ±os, 1985, 24\n']
 ['090-102  XX', 'XX', 20, 'Abcdefg,Female,95 y mÃ¡s aÃ±os, 1985, 24\n']
 ['090-102  XX', 'XX', 20, 'Abcdefg,Female,95 y mÃ¡s aÃ±os, 1985, 24\n'] 
 ['090-102  XX', 'XX', 20, 'Abcdefg,Female,95 y mÃ¡s aÃ±os, 1985, 24\n'] 
 ['090-102  XX', 'XX', 20, 'Abcdefg,Female,95 y mÃ¡s aÃ±os, 1985, 24\n']
 ['090-102  XX', 'XX', 20, 'Abcdefg,Female,95 y mÃ¡s aÃ±os, 1985, 24\n']]
```

I don't know if I should append the items first into the huge list, before separating it into sublists. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming all your lists are of the same length, otherwise, you have to fill the gaps first. I see you are trying to create a new list out of 3 (or more) lists and the new list has the same format to all of its elements. You might first split the items from your first list on the dots by:

```
newList1=[]
for i in list11:
   newList1.append(i.split('.'))
```

this will convert each element of your list to a list where the first item is whatever before the dot and the second item is whatever after the dot. Then adds this list the `newList1` variable.

after that, it is a simple for loop:

```
a = [['xx','xx'], ['yy', 'yy'] , [ 'zz', 'zz']]
b = [1,2,3]
c = [0, 00, 000]
newList2 = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    newList2.append(a[i][0]+str(b[i])+a[i][1]+str(c[i])) #adjust to your format
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for answering. I was able to split the items from my first list on the dots. However, when I try to do the for loop, I get this error: "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str"

Comment: You're right. We should convert any numeric values into strings. See my edit for the last line.